# How can I link a stylesheet with a media query such that it is downloaded only when the media query is satisifed

Tags: html, css, browser, web-performance

I include 2 stylesheets in a page, one is the version for mobile that is alwys required. on larger screens i would like to load desktop.css in addition. So I link the desktop style so:

```
 <link href="/css/desktop.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all and (min-width: 780px)" />
```

I thought that the browser would be clever enough to download desktop.css only on large screens. It loads it always however.

Is it possible to prevent the browser from downloading when the media query is not met?

Comment: Maybe you should look into CSS extension languages compass and sass?

Comment: thx but that such tools are developer time tools. i use sass. this question is about how to stop the browser from downloading the final css. which very such tool finally produces.

Comment: why do you not use jquery for getting the media size and **if min-width: 780px** then load the css or append the css to your header.

Comment: that is certainly a solution. would not need jquery for that but just plain vanilla js. my question is for a plain css solution though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not possible. For media queries the resource is still downloaded (though often at lower priority) but not applied.

This has always been the case even with `media=print` for example. The exact reasons aren’t clear to me, but there was a brief discussion [in this issue](https://github.com/w3c/preload/pull/117), suggesting it broke too many sites - sites presumably that checked the media queries in the CSSOM for even when they didn’t match. That issue clarifies that link `rel=“preload”` does honour the media query in terms of downloads but there is less risk of breakage there (preload is just an optimisation hint).

The fact that non-matching media queries are downloaded (but not render blocking) actually forms the basis of [a bit of a hack to load CSS async](https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/load-css-simpler/) with the following code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/my.css" media="print" onload="this.media='all'">
```

Comment: yepp, that hack is what i ended up with.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. It's a shame it works this way, I have a site where the design for the header on mobile is totally different to larger screens, so the CSS files are easy to separate. Yet the all the header CSS files will be downloaded by mobile phones even though they could never physically achieve the size required by the media query!